# invoke C function with struct as return value in C#

Tags: c#, c, struct, invoke

I simply want to call a C function from a DLL in C#. This C function returns a struct.

Here the .h-file declaration of the c dll:

```
typedef struct t_Point{
 int x;
 int y;
} Point;


Point myFuncs();
```

Now I want to use this function in C#. Wrapper.cs:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharp_mit_OpenCV
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Point
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    };

    class Wrapper
    {
        [DllImport("OpenCV Test.dll", CharSet= CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        public static extern Point myFuncs();
    }
}
```

The usage is as follows:

```
Point p = Wrapper.myFuncs();
```

(Naming is probably not the best)

myFuncs only declares a struct, puts some values to x and y and returns it. The problem: The values I get in C# are different than those generated in the C function. It should be 4 and 2 and it is 0 and 111226272. What's the problem here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Guess it's something with differences in types: try in C# `short` instead of `int`, and try with `uint` or `ushort`. Can you post the bytes that are outputted by the process (so before C# tries to create a struct from them)?

Comment: Is it always returning 111226272 or does the number differ every time?

Comment: Don't forget to make sure that the calling convention is correct (cdecl/fast-call, etc).  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your marshall code seems correct, what is the pack layout of the unmanaged method? LayoutKind.Sequential will treat your ints as 4 byte. Check if this is correct.